# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" always show on mu-editor at REPL mode with micro:bit

Tags: python, syntax-error, micropython, mu

I use mu-editor 1.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to do a very simple calculation such as "2+2"(without ""), the REPL mode always show the error message as follow:

```
on v1.9.2-34-gd64154c73 on 2017-09-01; micro:bit v1.0.0-rc.2 with 
nRF51822

Type "help()" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 2+2
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

and below is my screen:

[image]

I try to find out answer on internet, but I still can't figure out how and why. Please help me try to handle this problem.

Thank you so much anyway.

=============update 2017/07/25 18:48(Taiwan)==============

Thank you, Dear @stijn :)

I have made some progress on this issue. However, I still have not solved this problem completely.

In the following URL, a kind netizen provides a clue to solve the problem：
https://github.com/mu-editor/mu/issues/576

ZanderBrown said: "Can only assume there is some invisible char or something". This makes me wonder if it is possible to relate to my input method, input device, or language(locale).

Since I am a Taiwanese, we use Traditional Chinese (unlike Simplified Chinese used in mainland China). In **/etc/default/locale**, my original settings are as follows:

```
LANG="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="zh_TW:zh:en_US:en"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_TW.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_TW.UTF-8"
```

Then, I change the content to be as follow **first**:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_NAME=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=lzh_TW.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

**Second**, I tried to change my **Region & Language** to be English and United States.

[image]

Third, I set my **keyboard input method system** to be **none**

[image]

Finally, I reboot my system. We can see an interesting result：

[image]

If I copy the code from other text editor then paste on REPL mode, it can print correct result, but the words after >>> mark will be strange...

If I try to use keyboard to input directly, it will not repeat the characters, or not respond.
[image]

Besides, I can use minicom mode to use REPL, but it still repeat chars....

[image]

===================update 2017/07/26 14:26(Taiwan)==============
Thank you all. I have almost solved this problem. Here are my solutions and possible reasons.

My friend, a hardware engineer told me to try using a kit named **minicom** of linux. We connected micro:bit with PC(ubuntu), and then used the minicom to check the status of connection.

```
$ minicom /dev/ttyACM0
```

(if you want to know the port that you connect with micro:bit, you can use a command named dmesg.)
Select the **Serial and Port Setup**
[image]

Check the option **Serial Device** is as same as the result printed by dmesg. If it is not, change it.
And, the most important, keep the option **Hardware Flow Control** is **YES**. I don't understand the principle, but after testing, it is necessary to keep **YES**.
[image]

After above, you can choose **EXIT**(not EXIT from MINICOM) to enter the REPL mode in minicom with connecting micro:bit. You May can use python coding at the situation, even my console screen still show any character I input while I was keying once...

What I did on next step is **TOTALLY POWER OFF** my computer. And POWER ON my PC(ubuntu) again.

Miracle happened.

After I **TOTALLY POWER OFF and POWER ON** my pc(ubuntu) again, I can use REPL mode in MU-editor and minicom without twice-character and other problems.
Please forgive me can not put my ScreenSchot pic because I forgot bringing my micro:bit chip to my office.

However, on my laptop(Debian 9), the way I used as above can work after changing the input method system to en but Chinese input method.

So, I think the two main causes of the problems are:

1.Locale setting and Input method system: We are better to use **English locale setting** and **pure English input methods**.

2.Check the **Hardware Flow Control** is set on **YES**.

3.After setting all, please **TOTALLY POWER OFF** and POWER ON your pc or laptop again. **DO NOT just logout or reboot**.

Comment: Don't know mu-editor, but kind of looks like it's not sending proper termination and/or inserting spurious chracatres. Does the application have settings for REPL or serial line behaviour?

Comment: Thank you, @stijn. I have update the solution. :)

Comment: Very nice solution you found! May i suggest you edit your question, so that just the question is left, and then post the solution as an answer (you can mark your own anser as accepted on StackOverflow). That will be much handier for future visitors with the same question.

Comment: @stijn OK! Thanks for your kind suggestion. :) I will edit my question and post my own answer.